# How to play sound in MFC using Visual C++?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, alsa, directsound, pulseaudio

I would like to implement base band signal processing algorithms on my PC using my microphone input and speaker output. Which library do I need to use open/read/write audio equipment on Windows 7 64 bit? Can I do with MFC, or do I need to use a DirectSound wrapper Class to manipulate audio devices? I am also open to use GNU/Linux environment.

Comment: you are doing a strange mix here of oranges, apples and penguin meat...what does MFC has to do with GNU/Linux or DirectSound?

Comment: There is not mix with different OS and libraries. I just would like to manipulate audio interfaces on my PC. I have two different type of OS, MS Windows and Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [FMOD library](http://www.fmod.org/index.php/fmod), it is platform independent and it could be a good starting point. It is not GPL but it is free for non-commercial use. If you are willing to go on the "Windows-only" road, then take a look at Windows Core Audio APIs (Vista/Win7 only), DirectShow API (all windowses) or WINMM API (all windowses, probably easier to use than the other two). AFAIK, MFC does not provide any audio-specific classes.

Comment: I have installed FMOD library on my Windows 7. I could get 'recording example' to build.  As I understand from the library I need to use callbacks for captured discrete audio data. Can you suggest me any reference code for this?